# atmosphere js client, android, cordova, angular ui router issue when changing views

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, atmosphere

I am currently using atmosphere js client (talking to atmosphere java server) in a webapp for mobiles using ionic/cordova.  I am experiencing an odd issue which appears related to online/offline messages, but only in android cordova packaged app (standalone desktop browsers are fine, ios emulator is fine, even chrome browser using webapp on android is fine)

The atmosphere library connects fine and as long as I stay on the first page after initialization - it is fine. I receive updates etc.

As soon as I change view states in the ui-router ($state.go(....)) I experience network 'chatter' where it looks like atmosphere is responding to a network 'online' and 'offline' event being published.

It then gets itself into a weird state where it no longer is properly connected to server (no more update processed) and meanwhile because of logic I have on establishing a valid connection, bounce back to main screen, rending app unusable.

This is pretty reproducible for me on device and genymotion emulator.  Has anyone seen this issue?  Have you gotten a stable connection with this stack?

ionic 1.1 + crosswalk (cordova 4 I believe underneath) + angular 1.4.6 + 2.2.12 of atmosphere (tried both jquery and non-jquery version).  Using long-polling transport

EDIT:  adding my own listeners to online/offline - only called once on app start.  Putting break points in atmosphere.js (https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere-javascript/blob/master/modules/javascript/src/main/webapp/javascript/atmosphere.js) [near the bottom of file] and indeed these events are being fired seemingly for atmosphere only.  ng cordova network and my own hooks are not.

Comment: Kinda curious if you found any solutions to this problem? I am also experiencing weird timeout/connection (atmos + ionic) issues when running as an app (browser and emulator is fine)

Comment: sort of - but not likely what you want to hear.  I contributed a patch to atmosphere js lib to turn off atmosphere's handling of online/offline (handleOnlineOffline flag) which was accepted to mainline.  This worked for me because I have other things that need to happen during online/offline anyway and so I put my own reconnect logic around it in my own services/controllers from the cordova events

Comment: https://github.com/jtbdevelopment/TwistedBattleship/blob/master/ui/app/scripts/controllers/main.js